# Understanding the eigenvectors of the discrete Laplacian $A^h$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

I have the following theorem:

**Theorem:** In the one-dimensional problem and with elimination of boundary conditions, the matrix $A^h \in \mathbb{R}^{(N-1)\times(N-1)}$ has the following eigenvalues and eigenvectors $$A^h v^{h, [k]} = \lambda_k^hv^{h,[k]}$$ where for $k=1,\ldots,N-1$ $$v^{h,[k]} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N-1}}\begin{bmatrix}\sin(\pi k x_1)\\\vdots\\sing(\pi k x_{N-1)}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\sin(\pi k h)\\\vdots\\\sin(\pi k (N-1)h)\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\lambda_k^h = \dfrac{2}{h^2}[1-\cos(\pi h k)] = \dfrac{2}{h^2}2\sin^2(\dfrac{\pi h k}{2}).$$

The proof begins like this:

**Proof:** For an index $i$ corresponding to a node that is not connected to the boundary we have that $$[A^hv^{h,[k]}]_i = \sum\limits_{\alpha = 1}^{N-1}a_{i\alpha}\nu_\alpha^{h,[k]}\\ = \dfrac{1}{h^2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N-1}}[-\sin(\pi(i-1)h k) + 2\sin(\pi i h k) - \sin(\pi(i + 1)h k)]$$

**Question:** Why is the second equality in the proof correct? I has never been used before in my book and I have no clue why this would be true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the explicit form of the element $[A^h]_{ij} = a_{ij}$?

Comment: I think the field $\Bbb{R}$ has infinitely many elements, so the tag [tag:finite-fields] was inappropriate and I removed it.